# ReactJs: Input onChange requires to be updated each time to change the value in input

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, state

I have simple array object in react state with Id, name and age for three perons. I want to change the name using input. I have map function to render each person info with input field below and I change the name of the person with input field . Below is my code for

**app.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import 'Person' from 'person';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    persons: [
      { id: 'asfa1', name: 'Max', age: 28 },
      { id: 'vasdf1', name: 'Manu', age: 29 },
      { id: 'asdf11', name: 'Stephanie', age: 26 }
    ]
  }

  nameChangedHandler = ( event, id ) => {
    const personIndex = this.state.persons.findIndex(p => {
      return p.id === id;
    });

    const person = {
      ...this.state.persons[personIndex]
    };

    // const person = Object.assign({}, this.state.persons[personIndex]);

    person.name = event.target.value;

    const persons = [...this.state.persons];
    persons[personIndex] = person;

    this.setState( {persons: persons} );
  }

  render() {
    let persons = null;
    persons = (
      <div> 
        {this.state.persons.map((person,index) =>{
          return <Person key={person.name}
          changed={(event) => this.nameChangedHandler(event, person.id)}
          name={person.name}
          age={person.age} />
        })}
      </div>
    )
    return ( 
      <div> 
        {persons} 
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**persons.js**

```
import React from 'react';

function Person(props) {
  return(
    <div>
      <p> Hello my name is {props.name} and age {props.age} </p>
      <input type="text" onChange={props.changed} value = {props.name} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Person
```

And the problem I am facing is that I have to enter a value into input field by click or selecting the input field each time the value is entered and also state is being updated for every single character changed in input field. How should I fix this  ? . Any ideas to help me understand my mistake here is welcome and thanks in advance. hope my question is understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue comes from your `key` prop logic when you render your `<Person>` list.
Take a look at the doc, [the section about lists and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

The thing is, everytime the name input changes, the key of your `<Person>` changes (since you set the key to equal the name) and therefore another instance of `<Person>` is actually rendered. Keys set the identity of a component. What you want is using keys that have an identity semantic, which mean they never change over time. In your case, use the `id` field from your array.

```
{this.state.persons.map((person, index) => (
  <Person
    key={person.id}
    changed={(event) => this.nameChangedHandler(event, person.id)}
    name={person.name}
    age={person.age}
  />
))}
```

Comment: ..Thanks mate it works,  this mistake happened because I wasn't having patience to check it properly.  I added Id in array for key but I didn't use it.